# How do I remove code duplication in two identical Haskell functions with different output type?

Tags: haskell

I continue experimenting with Haskell and GUI
https://github.com/bigos/cairo-example/blob/1c4448a936031b0e5b66b77027be975d040df01b/src/Main.hs
and I've ran into another problem.

I have two identical functions with different result type:

```
getWidgetSize :: Gtk.DrawingArea -> Render (Int, Int)
getWidgetSize widget = do
  width'  <- fromIntegral <$> Gtk.widgetGetAllocatedWidth widget
  height' <- fromIntegral <$> Gtk.widgetGetAllocatedHeight widget
  return (width', height')

getWidgetSize2 :: Gtk.DrawingArea -> IO (Int, Int)
getWidgetSize2 widget = do
  width'  <- fromIntegral <$> Gtk.widgetGetAllocatedWidth widget
  height' <- fromIntegral <$> Gtk.widgetGetAllocatedHeight widget
  return (width', height')
```

One is used in this function

```
updateCanvas :: Gtk.DrawingArea -> Model -> Render ()
```

and the other is used in the main function.

Is it possible to remove the code duplication?

## solution

Following Vora's advice I have used the following:

```
getWidgetSize :: Gtk.DrawingArea -> IO (Int, Int)
getWidgetSize widget = do
  width'  <- fromIntegral <$> Gtk.widgetGetAllocatedWidth widget
  height' <- fromIntegral <$> Gtk.widgetGetAllocatedHeight widget
  return (width', height')

updateCanvas :: Gtk.DrawingArea -> Model -> Render ()
updateCanvas canvas model = do
  size <- liftIO (getWidgetSize canvas)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use the fact that `Render` is a `MonadIO`, meaning you could simply make one `IO` typed definition, and `liftIO` the call when inside the `Render` Monad.
Edit:
As per Carl's suggestion, and since `widgetGetAllocatedWidth`/`widgetGetAllocatedHeight` are constrained on the `MonadIO` requisite, you could also make a

```
getWidgetSize :: MonadIO m => Gtk.DrawingArea -> m (Int, Int)
getWidgetSize widget = do
  width'  <- liftIO $ fromIntegral <$> Gtk.widgetGetAllocatedWidth widget
  height' <- liftIO $ fromIntegral <$> Gtk.widgetGetAllocatedHeight widget
  return (width', height')
```

which would then work in both scenario. This is mostly equivalent, however it allows it to be called the same way from any `MonadIO` context.

Edit2: (Because more edits is always better right guys)
Edit3: Because sometimes you look at something from too close, and you miss it.
The `liftIO`, which I moved inside the `do` block for clarity, can also be removed to declutter the field a bit :

```
getWidgetSize :: MonadIO m => Gtk.DrawingArea -> m (Int, Int)
getWidgetSize widget = do
  width'  <- fromIntegral <$> Gtk.widgetGetAllocatedWidth widget
  height' <- fromIntegral <$> Gtk.widgetGetAllocatedHeight widget
  return (width', height')
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use the type GHC infers for the definition?

Comment: Would you need the liftIO at all? Since all the actions you're using are already generalized to MonadIO I expect you could leave it out entirely.

Comment: As a matter of fact, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can reason over the types:

- [**`widgetGetAllocatedWidth :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO m, IsWidget a) => a -> m Int32`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.22/docs/GI-Gtk-Objects-Widget.html#v:widgetGetAllocatedWidth)
- [**`widgetGetAllocatedHeight :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO m, IsWidget a) => a -> m Int32`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.22/docs/GI-Gtk-Objects-Widget.html#v:widgetGetAllocatedHeight)
- [**`(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36--62-)
- [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral)
- [**`(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-)
- [**`return :: Monad m => a -> m a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return)

First we can desugar the `do`-block:

```
getWidgetSize widget = do
  width'  <- fromIntegral <$> widgetGetAllocatedWidth widget
  height' <- fromIntegral <$> widgetGetAllocatedHeight widget
  return (width', height')
```

is syntactical sugar for:

```
getWidgetSize widget = fromIntegral <$> widgetGetAllocatedWidth widget >>= \w' -> (
    fromIntegral <$> widgetGetAllocatedHeight widget >>= \h' -> (
        return (w', h')
    )
)
```

So first we assume `getWidgetSize` has type `a -> b`, and we assume `widget :: a` (we will later work out what `a`, `b`, etc are).

Next we see that there is a call `widgetGetAllocatedWidth widget`, so that means that `(HasCallStack, MonadIO m, IsWidget a)` holds, and that `widgetGetAllocatedWidth widget` has return type `m Int32`, so we now know:

```
getWidgetSize :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO m, IsWidget a) => a -> b
widget :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO m, IsWidget a) => a
widgetGetAllocatedWidth widget :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO m, IsWidget a) => m Int32
```

So now we perform a `(<$>) fromIntegral (widgetGetAllocatedWidth widget)` so that means that:

```
(<$>) :: Functor f => (c -> d) -> f c -> f d
fromIntegral :: (Integral c, Num d) => c -> d
widgetGetAllocatedWidth widget :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO m, IsWidget a) => m Int32
```

So we conclude that `f ~ m` and `c ~ Int32`, and that:

```
(<$>) fromIntegral (widgetGetAllocatedWidth widget) :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO m, IsWidget a, Num d, Functor m) => m d
```

The same holds for the second part `fromIntegral <$> widgetGetAllocatedHeight widget`, since the signature of `widgetGetAllocatedHeight` is the same as `widgetGetAllocatedWidth`, we conclude that:

```
(<$>) fromIntegral (widgetGetAllocatedHeight widget) :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO n, IsWidget a, Num e, Functor n) => n e
```

Note that here the `n` is *not* per se the same as `m` (later it will turn out it is), and that `e` is *not* per se the same as `d`.

Now we thus have three parts of the function (we will shorter the first two parts to `f` and `g`, such that) our function looks like:

```
getWidgetSize widget = f widget >>= (\w -> g widget >>= (\h -> return (w, h)))
```

With

```
f :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO m, IsWidget a, Num e, Functor m) => m d
g :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO n, IsWidget a, Num e, Functor n) => n e
```

Since the `(>>=)` function has as signature `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, we thus know that the `w` variable has type `Num d => d`.

We furthermore know that the part `g >>= \h -> return (w, h)` has as type:

```
g >>= \h -> return (w, h) :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO n, IsWidget a, Num d, Num e, Functor n) => n (d, e)
```

Since we we "bind" `f` with `\w -> g >>= \h -> return (w, h)`, we know that `m ~ n`. And so we come to the conclusion that the type of the result is:

```
(HasCallStack, MonadIO m, IsWidget a, Num d, Num e, Functor m) => m (d, e)
```

Now we can remove some duplication: since a `MonadIO` is defined as:

> ```
> class Monad m => MonadIO m where
>     -- ...
> ```

and since that:

> ```
> class Applicative m => Monad m where
>     -- ...
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> ```
> class Functor m => Applicative m where
>     -- ...
> ```

We know that `MonadIO m`, actually implies `Functor m`, so we can remove `Functor m`, so the final type for the implementation is:

```
getWidgetSize :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO m, IsWidget a, Num b, Num c) => a -> m (b, c)
getWidgetSize widget = do
  width'  <- fromIntegral <$> widgetGetAllocatedWidth widget
  height' <- fromIntegral <$> widgetGetAllocatedHeight widget
  return (width', height')
```

Comment: Thank you for the lecture. I always found it difficult to learn from abstract examples and your detailed discussion of a concrete problem I had will definitely help. While I can write both monad syntaxes I need to improve my reasoning.

Comment: I have read it few times over and over again and it begins to make sense. :-)